# Kubuntu 16.10: Second monitor background stuck with loading screen and not updated - strange behaviour

Tags: kubuntu, multiple-monitors

I have a strange problem on kubuntu 16.10 with second screen. The loading bar stays on the second screen after log in. I can drag a window to the screen but the background does not get updated so I can "paint" the whole background with the window when dragging.

Compositor is disabled. With compositor enabled, the second screen kind of works, but I cannot add a control bar or background image (it's just black) or have right-click context menu. I also had to force the font dpi to 96 because otherwise the letters are huge.

System is a Lenovo Thinkpad T420s in dock with the laptop screen disabled, one monitor connected with display port to HDMI adpater, the second one with VGA. Display driver is nvidia-375.

Bios is set to nvidia optimus. I played around with this setting. Since the intel integrated graphics is not routed to display port at all hardware-wise, I need to use the Nvidia NVS 4200M graphics. When I set it to discrete (=nvidia) only, Kubuntu won't boot.

Everything works fine when I use just the laptop screen.

xrandr shows both screens:

```
[...]
    DP-1 connected 1920x1200+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 160mm x 90mm
    1920x1200     59.95*+
[...]
    VGA-1-1 connected 1920x1200+1920+0 518mm x 324mm
    1920x1200     59.95*+
[...]
```

nvidia-settings only detects DP-1.

I have no idea how to start investigating the problem and need some guidance.